# Images do not show up on published pages

Tags: custom, publishing

I created a new page layout from Publishing - Pages. From there I added an image report control on my page allowing users to upload a required picture for this particular kind of page.

When the page is extracted, I can add a picture, save and the image will show up. However, as soon as I publish the page and refresh, the image disappears.

Any idea what might be the cause of this very weird issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: Perhaps the image must be published as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "when the page is extracted" ?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this before but not had time to dig in and identity the cause. But it looks like a CSS positioning issue. The quick work-around is to add some content (text) to the page. I only saw the problem when the page had no content other than the image.

Answer (score -1):

Were the images created in the CMYK colour format? If so please convert to RGB and upload again.

Comment: Are you sure this can be a cause? Why would SharePoint care what format an image is in, thats upto the browser to display it as far as SharePoint knows its just a collection of bits.

Comment: @Ryan not sure what the issue would pertain to, but at a guess blawrence may believe that the image is being resized or something and the resizer is causing it. However I do see you most likely aren't. Hi Blawrence welcome to SharePoint StackExchange, I would like to take this opportunity to point you at the [FAQ][1], this will detail everything you need to know when answering questions. [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq